# Swift returning an UIImageView after remote image finished downloading

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I'm using this library https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda

```
self.swipeView.dataSource = self
```

I have set the dataSource to self and Koloda requires the datasource method which returns a UIView. The problem I am having as this task is happening in the background, the method is returning before the image is fetched and returns nil.
Also Skeets ImageManger only seems to allow me to return Void in the success.

How do I get round this?

```
func kolodaViewForCardAtIndex(koloda: KolodaView, index: UInt) -> UIView {
    var imageView: UIView!
    ImageManager.fetch("http://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/109/590x/364016_1.jpg",
        progress: { (status: Double) -> Void in
            println(status)
        }, success: { (data: NSData) -> Void in
            imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(data: data))
        }) { (error: NSError) -> Void in
        println(error)
    }

    return imageView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create UIImageView and return it.
When success handler is called you can set the image for image view.

```
func kolodaViewForCardAtIndex(koloda: KolodaView, index: UInt) -> UIView {
            var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectZero)
            ImageManager.fetch("http://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/109/590x/364016_1.jpg",
                progress: { (status: Double) -> Void in
                    println(status)
                }, success: { (data: NSData) -> Void in
                    imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }) { (error: NSError) -> Void in
                println(error)
            }

            return imageView
    }
```